# Solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of a trigonometric function after implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'm supposed to implicitly differentiate $\sin(x+y)=2x-2y$. I've already taken the first derivative and got

$$
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}+1\right)\cdot\cos(y+x)=-2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-1\right)
$$

[www.derivative-calculator.net](http://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=sin%28x%2By%29%3D2x-2y&simplify=1&showsteps=1&implicit=y) says solving this equation for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ equals

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\cos(y+x)-2}{\cos(y+x)+2}
$$

But I'm lost when it comes to the algebra used to rewrite the equation in terms of $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Any help getting from point A to B will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These 2 equations are trivially equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}+1\right)\cdot\cos(y+x)=-2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-1\right)
$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cos(y+x)+\cos(y+x)=-2\frac{dy}{dx}+2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cos(y+x)+2\frac{dy}{dx}=2-\cos(y+x)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}(\cos(y+x)+2)=-(-2+\cos(y+x))$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\cos(y+x)-2}{\cos(y+x)+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

So,
$$\sin(x+y) = 2(x-y)$$
thus
$$\cos(x+y)+\frac{dy}{dx}\cos(x+y)=2-2\frac{dy}{dx}$$ Or
$$\cos(x+y)\left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=2\left(1-\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$
Re-arranging
$$\cos(x+y)\frac{dy}{dx}+2\frac{dy}{dx}=2-\cos(x+y)$$
Hence,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}(2+\cos(x+y) = -(\cos(x+y)-2)$$
From which
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\cos(x+y)-2}{\cos(x+y)+2}$$